# What happens when Push Notification is turned off ? Will code be executed (minus UI)?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Customers can turn off push notifications at the app level. When that happens, we all know the the notification tray UI will not show up. But,

- Does GCM/FCM (android) and APNS (iOS) continue to deliver notification to the customer's phone regardless ?
- Specifically, on android & iOS, will I be able to execute some logic in the push event listener regardless of whether the user turned the push notifications on/off ?
- In Android, when we disable push notifications, does the OS automatically  unregister the app from GCM/FCM ?

**Note:** 
I am NOT interested in background app refresh on iOS or background refresh through WorkManager on Android. I am NOT interested in iOS silent notifications or other kinds of Background Executions.

**My question is specifically whether the code block is invoked (or not) when push notifications are turned off at app level (using the toggle).**

Comment: Why not test it?

Comment: I don't have a quick way to test it right now. Tried looking for official documentation.

Comment: As far as I know, on Android it should execute. Android just suppresses the UI element, not the entire module.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the android, but in iOS this thing is possible.

You can do this but just keep in mind, that **Background App Refresh** is enable in device.

For more details, look into this link

https://www.urbanairship.com/blog/watch-list-ios-8-opt-in-changes

I hope you get your answer from above link

Comment: I am aware that I can do it with silent notifications with Background App Refresh enabled. But as mentioned in my note in the original questions, my question is specifically about regular push notifications. 

The article says "In the past, silent pushes were used for Newsstand apps; the silent push would trigger the download of new articles/issues in the background. When a user opted out of push, they would no longer receive these pushes." 

So I guess in iOS, the answer is push notifications handling block will not be executed when push notification is turned off at app level ? Thanks.